# Source Not Found when using ListFragment & ViewPager

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager, android-listfragment

I've been trying to create a simple Horizontal scrolling option.
I have 2 ListFragments, which I would like to scroll between.

I'm getting a "Source Not Found" error when returning the View from onCreateView function.

**This is my MainActivity Class:**

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {

    AppSectionsPagerAdapter mAppSectionsPagerAdapter;
    ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mAppSectionsPagerAdapter = new AppSectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mAppSectionsPagerAdapter);
        mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
            }
        });
        for (int i = 0; i < mAppSectionsPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
            actionBar.addTab(
                    actionBar.newTab()
                            .setText(mAppSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i))
                            .setTabListener(this));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, android.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, android.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
        // When the given tab is selected, switch to the corresponding page in the ViewPager.
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, android.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    }

    public static class AppSectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public AppSectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }
        Fragment a;
        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int i) {
            switch (i) {
                case 0:
                    return new FragmentA();

                default:
                    return new FragmentB();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 2;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return "Section " + (position + 1);
        }
    }
}
```

**This is one of my ListFragment class (the second is the same but different name & layout file):**

```
    public class FragmentA extends ListFragment {

        @Override
            public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.favorites_layout, container, false);
                updateStationsView(0);
                return rootView;
            }
}
```

updateStationView is a function that populates the List. removing it did not help, so I figured it's harmless.

The error is thrown right after the:

```
return rootView;
```

which returns to the onCreate functions of MainActivity.

**When I'm changing the ListFragment to be a simple Fragment it works**. I think I'm lacking some knowledge to figure this one out. I really want to use ListFragment...

Can someone please try an help ?
Many thanks for your efforts.

Adding the XML files:

activity_main.xml:

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

favorites_layout.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:orientation="vertical"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent">

   <ListView 
     android:id="@+id/list"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: could you post the error log?

Comment: Change the id of your ListView to "android:id="@android:id/list"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I im quite sure the issue is that your custom layout for the ListFragment does not contain a ListView. These lines of code are causing the error because you need to have a ListView inside your "favourites_layout" .xml file.

```
 @Override
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.favorites_layout, container, false);
      updateStationsView(0);
      return rootView;
 }
```

> ListFragment has a default layout that consists of a single list view.
>   However, if you desire, you can customize the fragment layout by
>   returning your own view hierarchy from onCreateView(LayoutInflater,
>   ViewGroup, Bundle). To do this, your view hierarchy must contain a
>   ListView object with the id "@android:id/list" (or list if it's in
>   code)

So your layout could for example look like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:orientation="vertical"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent">

   <ListView 
     android:id="@android:id/list"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

See here for more:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListFragment.html

Comment: I have changed the XML file to contain a LinearLayout with a single ListView element. Please see the the new XML in the main topic. it didn't help.

Comment: Please read my full answer. You need to set the id of your listview to "@android:id/list"

Comment: I'm sorry. missed the "android" part. Thanks a lot - it's working!